# How do I pass url array query parameter into Play Framework?

Tags: playframework, query-string

I want to have a controller and route that take an array parameter.

```
GET   /path    controllers.MyController.path(ids: Seq[Long])
```

How do I pass in the array parameter in the query string of the URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following URL:

```
/path?ids=1&ids=2
```